# React router routing to component with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, routes, react-router

I am developing a react application .Its has two single page application currently running on two ports 8081 and 8082.
One is **dashboard** and other is **view**.
Using react router dom,
I am trying to route from view which is running on port 8082 to dashboard which is running on 8081.

I am able to successfully route to dashboard's app.js.

Inside dashboard I have a route to another component booking.

Here when I am trying to route to this booking component `dashboard/booking` from **view** I am getting an error. `cannot get dasboard/booking` in the browser

Comment: I think you need to change the location of the current tab to go entirely to a new url and its router will mount the desired component

Comment: Try to use **window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8081/dashboard/booking'**. Hope it is working